# fn.apply with first param null or undefined

Tags: javascript

I am confused with [`fn.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). For example,

Consider this snippet

```
Array.min = function(){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, arr );
}
```

I can grasp this. I understand fn.apply as,

> Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array

But the below snippets also work

```
Array.min = function(){
    return Math.min.apply( null, arr );
}

Array.min = function(){
    return Math.min.apply( undefined, arr );
}
```

MDN explains this as,

> if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and
>   undefined **will be replaced with the global object, and primitive
>   values will be boxed**

I don't really understand the part which I have made bold. What is the meaning of that statement? Could anyone elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 9):

The "global object" is the global object. Just [read the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1):

> The unique global object is created before control enters any execution context.
>
> In addition to the properties defined in this specification the global object may have additional host defined properties. This may include a property whose value is the global object itself; for example, in the HTML document object model the `window` property of the global object is the global object itself.

In the browser, you're essentially calling `Math.min.apply(window, arr)`, which you can verify:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this);  // Logs `Window {...}`
}).apply(undefined);
```

This is one of the many problems with non-strict mode. `this` sometimes becomes `window`, and you silently end up creating global properties. In strict mode, `this` will truly be `undefined`:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    (function() {
        console.log(this);  // Logs `undefined`
    }).apply(undefined);
})();
```

"Primitive values will be boxed" just says that primitives like numbers and strings will be "boxed" into a container object because primitives themselves are not objects. Again, you can verify this:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this);  // Logs `Number {}`, not `2`
}).apply(2);
```

Here's some more info on primitives: [Why are JavaScript primitives not instanceof Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938680/why-are-javascript-primitives-not-instanceof-object)

Comment: is the global object `window` in case of nodejs as well ??

Comment: @vdua: Node.js uses `global`.

Answer (score 0):

**if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object**

i.e. window in case of browsers, I am not sure what it refers to in case of nodejs,

**and primitive values will be boxed**

primitive values will be wrapped into their corresponding Objects, i.e. in case of `fn.apply(2, args)` the variable `this` inside `fn` will refer to a Number Object whose value will be 2.