# Why 'Cannot read property 'x' of undefined' is not evaluated to false?

Tags: javascript

I have encountered the error 'Cannot read property 'x' of undefined' multiple times, and I know that I can manage to work around it by doing the famous

```
if (foo && foo.bar)
```

But the question is **WHY** ? Why do we need to check that object exists to test that his properties are defined or not ? Wouldn't be easier for everyone (approximately, we can safely exclude the guys building JavaScript engines) to test only the target property, and the JavaScript engine do the 'foo &&' behind the scenes ?

Many tears were shed, and more nights were spent sleepless debugging this error, so why the JS engine implementors chose to do it this way ? Is it a part of the specification of ECMAScript ([Spec website](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation))? Is it to laugh at newbies ? Is it a conspiration from StackOverflow to make more people visiting their website and ask the same question over and over ?

Ok, it is a part of the ECMAScript specs : [The Reference Specification Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reference-specification-type) (Normally. I am not that expert in reading formal, suit-and-tie-wearing-man-toned documents, but it should be it).

It is a language construct, but why can't they make it easier for the miserable developers using it ?

This question is about learning more about how JavaScript works, so it would be nice if you can explain things in depth.

And for the sake of the completeness of the question, a working example : jsfiddle.net/vr6bgwop/

Comment: In an alternate universe, men2n1 asked "Why is accessing a property on an undefined/null giving me `false` and not an error? Is it to laugh at newbies?"

Comment: @Zirak: That, and it also wouldn't mention which of the "parents" is the culprit. Which makes debugging it a pain in the ass.

Comment: Following the rules of stackoverflow, this question should be closed as **Too broad** and **Primary opinion based**.

Comment: How is this opinion based, @MarcosPérezGude?

Comment: Read: *miserable developers*, *laugh at newbies*, *commercial stackoverflow strategy* (in other words), etc. This is not a good asked question, even the question is large and with many asks inside it. Almost too broad, but I think that question makes all of you laugh and nobody marks it as should be closed. I laugh very minutes too, but this doesn't  pass the stackoverflow rules test.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: That was ironic, not expressing an opinion. And the question is not even broad. It is asking why evaluating a child of an undefined property will be different (throw an error) than evaluating the undefined property itself (undefined property of an undefined property should lead to undefined, not throw an error, in the logic of the question). So I was asking why this behavior was chosen over the 'logical' one. Understanding this aspect for language will benefit as all, I think.

Answer (score 7):

Let's look at some semi-related constructs of the language:

- Accessing an object's property which doesn't exist (e.g. `var foo = {}; foo.a`) results in `undefined`
- Passing less (or more) arguments than the function expects is legal; accessing a parameter that wasn't passed results in `undefined`
- Doing math operations on non-numbers results in `NaN`, which propagates through the computation (spot the object: `a * b - c ^ d`, you can't can you?)

And so forth. One can argue that the following all of the examples above *should* throw an error. Yet they don't, and it's not to save CPU cycles or memory, it's because of how the language works, and a history of fuck-ups. That last one is really, really important.

### It's how the language works: Objects and primitives

But let's talk about your example. Why even throw an error?

Contrary to popular belief, not everything in JS is an object: Most things can be *turned* into an object (see [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17938680/617762) if you're interested), but there are two very important *primitives* which cannot, namely `null` and `undefined`.

Let's look at that for a bit: If you could say that `null` and `undefined` can be turned into objects, then there'd be no problem accessing their properties, right?

Well, languages like Ruby do that. In Ruby, truly everything is an object, so you can do this: `nil.nil?` (see [example](https://repl.it/BKOQ)). Trying to access a non-existing property (or slot? was that how they called it?) raises an exception like it does on any other objects (why are they raising exceptions!? can't they just return `undefined`?)

But most other languages don't. Famously, `null` values and friends are there to represent that which is nothing, Not an Object in languages which are familiar with that concept. In Java and C# the `NullReferenceException` is famous. In C++ it's worse: de-referencing a `null` causes a segfault! Imagine debugging that!

Therefore, considering the history of the language and its having both objects and primitives, it makes sense to throw an error if you can't treat a primitive like an object.

### Imagine that world

Let's say that you're correct: The distinction is stupid, it should be implemented. You raise a bug report, TC39 (the ones in charge of specifying javascript) agree, it's implemented everywhere. Content, you go to your favourite editor, write this smack in the middle of things:

```
foo.bar.baz = 4
```

And for some reason, something else in a pretty unrelated part of your system which gets passed `foo.bar.baz` in some obscure fashion throws weird errors, about `false` not having a `toFixed` function.

wtf? How did this happen? How do you *approach* debugging it?

After several hours of debugging and working your way back through the call stack, you smack your forehead in disbelief. "I'm an idiot", you say to yourself, "how could I have forgotten to initialize `foo.bar`?"

That's why I also personally think that `NaN` propagation is a disaster.

### But why did you get so worked up?

But finally, let's clear something out of the way: Why did this error cause you hours of debugging? Since this is an exception, it clearly shows you the line and column it happened in, and you obviously know this rule, so the distance from error to finding the right spot is nearly instantaneous. That's the point you should work on, language idiosyncrasies aside.

### Aside: Where it is in the spec

You were close to where this behaviour is specified. Luckily for you (and sadly for me...) I've read a lot of that formal, suit-and-tie-wearing-man-toned document, and knew how to find this.

Searching for [Property Accessors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-property-accessors), you get to the [Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) section. Note step 7 of the first algo, and step 4 of the second:

> Let `bv` be [`RequireObjectCoercible(baseValue)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-requireobjectcoercible).

In the `RequireObjectCoercible` table, we see that `undefined` and `null` throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: Great answer, which could be used to close similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the overhead of checking *all* parents of `z` in `a.b.c.d....x.y.z`, *every* time you need to access `z`.

That's why you explicitly have to check for missing properties, yourself. There is no way to automatically check it without **significantly increasing memory / CPU usage**.

---

That said, if you were to automatically return, for example, `undefined` if one of the parents isn't set, then you'd have no way of knowing whether `z` is undefined, or if one of it's parents is.

How would you then make sure it's parents are properly set? By manually checking each parent.

Comment: it may be *more* efficient if the JS engine returned `undefined` as soon as it hit an unknown token rather than throwing an error.

Comment: This is a simple issue, because if b is undefined, the engine will stop at c and just return false, without checking all the children (no need to do that because if the father is undefined, there will no child, unless the mother did it in vitro)

Comment: There is no additional overhead. JS already does all the required checks. It simply only reveals the result as an exception. Consider `(function(){try{return a.b.c.d....x.y.z}catch(e){if(e instanceof TypeError){return null}throw e;}}())` as the JS version of C#'s null-conditional operator  `a?.b?.c?.d?....x?.y?.z`

Comment: @men1n2: But, if `y` is undefined, you have a load of checks before it.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Then you'd have no way of knowing if `z` is undefined, or if one of it's parents is.

Comment: In either case the fix would be to do some of the lookups and then store the result in a variable. And then do the rest.

Comment: @Cerbrus, correct, and I think that would be a good answer to the OP's post.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: I expanded on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't be easier for everyone (approximately, we can safely exclude
>   the guys building JavaScript engines) to test only the target
>   property, and the JavaScript engine do the 'foo &&' behind the scenes
>   ?

Of course they could. And it would be much slower due to the extra tests required, also in all the cases where the developer bloody well knows that `foo` cannot be null:

```
foo = { bar: (i == 50) };
if(foo.bar) {...}
```

Developer laziness is never an excuse for slowing down a language. In your case, you are evaluating 2 conditions: whether `foo` is even set, and if it is, whether its property `bar` is set. If you test 2 conditions, you write both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript don't allows you to access non-existing properties equal all programming languages. It's a feature that forces you to develop with good practices. There are a lot of methods to avoid your problem in an `if` statement, for example initialize objects with null or undefined values:

```
 var foo = {
      bar: null,
      beer: undefined
 }

 if(foo.beer) { 
      // you'll never notice with an undefined error, so undefined is the value!
 }
```

And please, don't be conspiranoic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not talking about accessing the value of a property. It is about evaluating its existence. If it does not exist, by itself, or because its parent does not exist, why the first case will return false and the second an error ?
I know that evaluating the statement inside if means to 'access its value' and see whatever comes out to convert it to boolean. But, if direct children properties return undefined -> false, why can't indirect children of nonexistent parent return the same and not throw an error ?

Am not being conspiranoic, but it is a conspiracy against us

Comment: So it can't return false if a property doesn't exists. I haven't trouble with it. I don't know why you have it. It's better throws an error than returns false. And it's better if you manage these errors than read a false *false* returned value.You'll get more problems if you read a false in a non-existing property. It's not a conspiracy of stackoverflow hahaha. I recognize that you makes me laugh a lot this morning. Thank you for that :)